# How can I set the output directory for a Pig STORE command?

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig, azure-hdinsight

I am using Pig via Azure HDInsight. I am able to submit a query that ends with a STORE, something like this:

```
STORE Ordered INTO 'results' USING PigStorage(',');
```

That works, storing the output in the directory `/user/hdp/results/`. However I would like to control the output directory. I've tried both...

```
STORE Ordered INTO '/myOutDir/results' USING PigStorage(',');
```

and

```
STORE Ordered INTO 'wasb:///myOutDir/results' USING PigStorage(',');
```

Neither of those works. They both generate this error:

```
Ordered was unexpected at this time.
```

My question is, can I control the output directory for a Store command? Or does it have to go in the user directory?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to set the output with a parameter you can do this :

```
 STORE Ordered INTO '$myOutDir/results' USING...
```

And then run your script with :

```
 pig -param myOutDir=/blablabla/... myScript.pig
```

NB: you can also set a default value to your parameter, add at the top of your script :

```
%default myOutDir '/blablabla/...'
```

Hope this help, good luck :)

Answer (score 0):

Use output path as below

```
wasb[s]://<BlobStorageContainerName>@<StorageAccountName>.blob.core.windows.net/<path>
```

If your output path `/example/data/sample.log` then use

```
wasb://mycontainer@mystorageaccount.blob.core.windows.net/example/data/sample.log
wasb:///example/data/sample.log
```

I hope this may help you. :-)